# BroadcastReceiver using 1 time

Tags: java, android, mysql

Good evening, I have a simple program that activates the BroadcastReceiver to detect the number when I receive a call, the problem is that when I get the call, will write again in my database, and when I disconnect the call records again, summing writes 3 ​​times! and I only want 1, when it is playing!
Another problem is when the phone is ringing, writes logo in the database, (here is okay!) But it does not answer the call, it writes the call again!
    the code is this:

my broadcast: its works!

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    String idtelemovel="1";
    String phone_number;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Entrou no BroadCastReceiver!!! : ");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        phone_number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        System.out.println("Phone Number : " + phone_number);
        Log.i("zz", "Phone Number : " + phone_number);
        new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null); 
    }
    class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {    
        private void postData(String phone_number) {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.AAA.com/insert.php");     
            try {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Street", phone_number));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("House", idtelemovel));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                }
            catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                    System.out.print("*********fail*********");
                }
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(phone_number);
        return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />    

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.BroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><service android:name=".MyServices" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check broadcast action, no?

Comment: Yes it works, only writes 2 times or 3 times in DB, I do not know if my explanation this very confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broadcast intent also includes the call state (idle, ringing, offhook). You can read it with the key [`Telephony.EXTRA_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_STATE), then compare it with the possible values. For example:

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
{
    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    // call your asynctask ...
}
```